# Read file PHP not working

Tags: php

I am having some major troubles having my files read through PHP. This is not something I've found challenging in the past but now nothing seem to be working for me. The following is a small demo of what I'm trying to do.

```
if(!is_readable("test.txt"))
{
    echo "Cannot not read file!";
    return false;
}
echo file_get_contents("test.txt");
$fh = fopen("test.txt","r");
while ($line = fgets($fh))
{
    echo $line;
}
```

What could be wrong? All code above have been taken from tutorials/examples which is why I'm having such a hard time understanding what's the problem.

I've set this file to have all permissions, just in case, and I have my error reporting on.

The result of the above code is nothing. It will accept that the file is readable, it will not complain saying the file path is wrong when I use fopen yet it will not display the contents of the `test.txt` file (yes it holds content xD).

My main theory of the issue is that it may be a configuration error of some sort as the script happily download urls (eg http://*).

Comment: firstly, your if statement is bad.. if its not readable, you still have it trying...

Comment: `while (($line = fgets($fh)) !== false) {`

Comment: Your code works for me without any issues.

Comment: @Pogrindis this was quick example... Might be bad practise but doesn't change the issue.

Comment: @Daan Does not make a difference.

Comment: Use parentheses on your `if` statements! Always!

Comment: @Xweque personally I would use `file_exists()` instead of `is_readable()`.

Comment: @Mr.E brackets are optional in PHP.

Comment: Optional but when code is not working they're advised! `$file = file_get_contents('./test.txt');
echo $file;` @Xweque try this as file_get_contents can return boolean sometimes without string representation.

Comment: @Pogrindis Didn't make a difference.

Comment: @PanamaJack It's not about whether it'll work, it's incredibly bad practice not to use them. It's the reason you get problems like this.

Comment: @Xweque then there is nothing in that file.. check does the file exist..

Comment: Do you see the file listed if you add `var_dump(glob('*'));`?

Comment: Also, can you write back with the result of `var_dump(file_get_contents("test.txt"));`?  It would be interesting to see if it returns `fase` (i.e. failure) or empty (meaning it thinks your file is empty).

Comment: @OzSolomon It's listed...

Comment: @Xweque can you run the second experiment I listed above?

Comment: @OzSolomon Very interesting with the var_dump. It return `string(633) " "` indicating that it has gotten the size right anyways, however no content...

Comment: @Xweque is your file UTF encoded (or otherwise not ASCII encoded)? You may have an output encoding issue.

Comment: @Mr.E it can make it more difficult to maintain however if you are writing code for yourself and not other developers to add to it, it's your choice. PHP doesn't give a requirement on this like other languages. But this is irrelevant to the problem anyway.

Comment: @OzSolomon It's ASCII encoded.

Comment: @Xweque I would `echo(bin2hex(file_get_contents(...)));` to see the hex representation of what PHP is reading.  It should help you figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your code example does nothing when it is readable?  What happens when you do this?

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);  // put this at top of script

if(!is_file("test.txt")){
    echo "Cannot not read file!";
}
else{
  echo 'is readable attempt to output contents';
  try {
      $fileContentAsString = file_get_contents("test.txt");
      var_dump($fileContentAsString);  // try this
      echo $fileContentAsString;
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
      //echo $e->getMessage();
      echo "it failed for some reason.. view output";
      var_dump($e);  // try this
  }
}
```

Comment: I edited my code to clarify. My issue has nothing to do with the is_readable check. It passed the test! My issue is with displaying the contents of the file...

Comment: what happens when you try the above.. if it cant get the content for some reason it will say why?..  In your example you are outputting the content of the file twice?..  also have you checked if your file contains content?

Comment: It's irrelevant that I output it twice, it was to show that none of the methods worked. The file contain content. Your code doesn't work either.

Comment: @Xweque instead of saying it doesn't work, try saying what happends. Do any of the error messages display?

Comment: There is no output. If there was I would be sharing but there is none.

Comment: why doesnt it work?  what does it output?..  may need a few tweaks but it should at least highlight the concept?  if it doesnt work it should the $e->getMessage giving you more clues to what the problem is.

Comment: do you have errors turned on..? -- ive modified answer to show this..  so when it runs it returns nothing at all?..  if thats the case then you need to strip out all the code and just have what ive put  (or something similar..)

Comment: I already have error reporting on... There are no errors, warnings or any output whatsoever.

Comment: it should output at least one of the following `"Cannot not read file!";` or
`'is readable attempt to output contents';` .. have you tried stripping away the rest of the php code so that it only contains the content from my example?  looks like its not reaching the code at all.

Comment: Oh, must have been some other internal error previously.. Now it outputs: `is readable attempt to output contents getMessage(); } } ?>`

Comment: it has a problem getting the contents of the file..  try the var_dump on the `$e`  (ive updated answer to show how to do that)... what does that output?

Comment: @Robbo_UK It now only outputs `is readable attempt to output contents`

Comment: ive made some changes.. what does it output now?

Comment: this is the best example of the person who answers doing the debugging for the OP.. Im gonna plus one this answer for effort alone!

Comment: @Robbo_UK `is readable attempt to output contentsstring(878) " getMessage(); echo "it failed for some reason.. view output"; var_dump($e); // try this } } ?> " getMessage(); echo "it failed for some reason.. view output"; var_dump($e); // try this } } ?>`

Comment: it shouldnt output php code keywords???? should not display keywords `echo`  or `var_dump`  are you actually running it via PHP..  eg.. `echo 'hello'` should just output `hello` not the echo part...

Comment: @Robbo_UK Clearly going above and beyond in a case where its not clear that the OP is making nearly the same effort.